# Formulas suddenly become text

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I've been working on an extensive Excel list with cell references between sheets and it's been working like a charm, up until now. There is this one cell that refuses to acknowledge that I have entered a formula. It just returns it as plain text no matter what format or value type I set on the cell.

When I click-and-drag-copy from the cell above, the formula works. However, due to how the sheet is built I do need to edit the cell slightly or it points to an incorrect reference (i.e. if it says `=sheet!A54` i have to change it to `=sheet1!A55`). When I edit the cell (F2) and enter the correct reference, the output value is all of a sudden the formula in plain text, not the value. Same thing if I empty the cell and enter the formula manually.

I am at a complete loss here and is wondering if anyone else has had this issue.

Comment: Format the cell as "general" not "text"

Comment: @DavidPostill as I wrote in the question, I have tried every format AND type - even "General".

Comment: What happens when you manually type a formula into another cell?